# How to modify a google sheets table ? (based on CRUD actions)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two input tables (Step 1 and Step 2 below) with a desired output (see below). I want to modify the Table1 with CRUD actions from Table2.

**Table 1**

I have a table that looks like:

| Level | Upper | Year | What | KPI | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 0.8 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.7 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 125 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.04 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 0.6 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.5 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 7 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 12530 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.03 |

The above table has 100+ rows.

**Table 2**

I have a second table where I put modifications on the "Table 1". This "Table 2" is only a few lines.

This Table 2 has same format as Table 1, and I add a last column with the action CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE. (Note: C, U, and D from [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete))

| Level | Upper | Year | What | KPI | Value | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 1.8 | UPDATE |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.7 | DELETE |
| Homeworking | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 | CREATE |

**Desired output**

The desired output is the combination of "initial data" in Table 1, with the modification from Table 2. Highlighted in **bold** the expected modifications.

What I am actually expecting, is that, if a row from Table 2 is matching a row on Table 1 (the match is on the first 5 columns), then the Table 2 action (create, update, delete) shall be done on Table 1, with the new value from Table 2.

| Level | Upper | Year | What | KPI | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | **1.8** |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 125 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.04 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 0.6 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.5 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 7 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 12530 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.03 |
| **Homeworking** | **DX** | **2020** | **REAL** | **MRTT** | **8** |

**Question**

How to obtain the desired output ?

Comment: Is there any way to uniquely identify each row? You need this for the UD actions. An ID for each row would work, though it seems to me that the combination of the `Level` and `KPI` columns is unique, or could there be multiples of the same KPI for the same Level? With some kind of primary key maybe an Apps Script solution could be worked out. I guess you just want to run these actions once and then mark them as done?

Comment: The unique id would be `A&B&C&D&E`. I can think of `={A2:F,arrayformula(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E)}` to create a table by adding an unique id column on the right, but what would be next? I am trying to avoid the GAS route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, this may be useful to someone, who knows.

For Table 1 and Table 2, I added an helper column, that column being a unique id of the row.

For Table 1, formula is `={A:F,arrayformula(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E)}` and it looks like:

| Level | Upper | Year | What | KPI | Value | LevelUpperYearWhatKPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 0.8 | HousingDX2020REALFIRST |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.7 | HousingDX2020REALLESS |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 | HousingDX2020REALMRTT |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 125 | HousingDX2020REALNB |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.04 | HousingDX2020REALOPEN |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 0.6 | PartyingDX2020REALFIRST |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.5 | PartyingDX2020REALLESS |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 7 | PartyingDX2020REALMRTT |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 12530 | PartyingDX2020REALNB |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.03 | PartyingDX2020REALOPEN |

For Table 2, similarly, formula is: `{H:N,arrayformula(H:H&I:I&J:J&K:K&L:L)}`, and it looks like:

| Level | Upper | Year | What | KPI | Value | Action | LevelUpperYearWhatKPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 1.8 | UPDATE | HousingDX2020REALFIRST |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.7 | DELETE | HousingDX2020REALLESS |
| Homeworking | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 | CREATE | HomeworkingDX2020REALMRTT |

Then I realized that :

1. UPDATE or DELETE action, shall lead to a suppression in Table 1.
2. UPDATE or CREATE action, shall lead to an addition in Table 1 (added from Table 2).

**Firstly**, let's suppress in Table 1, the rows that match from Table 2. Said in other words, let's suppress from Table 1 the rows where id is found in Table 2 with keywords UPDATE or DELETE. This is somewhat like filter a multi column list with another list.

Formula is:

```
QUERY({A2:F,arrayformula(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E)},
      "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col7<>'' and not Col7 matches '"
      &TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,
                QUERY({H2:N,arrayformula(H2:H&I2:I&J2:J&K2:K&L2:L)}, 
                      "select Col8 where Col7='UPDATE' or Col7='DELETE'"))
      &"' ")
```

That part `QUERY({H2:N,arrayformula(H2:H&I2:I&J2:J&K2:K&L2:L)}, "select Col8 where Col7='UPDATE' or Col7='DELETE'"))` is selecting from Table 2 the rows matching UPDATE or DELETE, and returns the id column.

That part `TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE, QUERY(...))` is building a regular expression (regex) like `id1|id2`

That part `QUERY({A2:F,arrayformula(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E)}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col7<>'' and not Col7 matches '"&TEXTJOIN(...)&"' ")` is selecting from Table 1 the id not found in Table 2.

**Secondly**, we need to add the rows from Table 2 that matched UPDATE or CREATE. Formula is `QUERY({H2:N},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col7='UPDATE' or Col7='CREATE' ")`

**Finally**, we have to concatenate the two results, and sort. Final formula is:

```
=SORT(
 {QUERY({A2:F,arrayformula(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E)},
        "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col7<>'' and not Col7 matches '"
        &TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,
                  QUERY({H2:N,arrayformula(H2:H&I2:I&J2:J&K2:K&L2:L)},
                        "select Col8 where Col7='UPDATE' or Col7='DELETE'"))
        &"' ")
 ;
 QUERY({H2:N},
        "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col7='UPDATE' or Col7='CREATE' ")
 })
```

And final result is:

| Level | Upper | Year | What | KPI | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Homeworking | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 1.8 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 8 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 125 |
| Housing | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.04 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | FIRST | 0.6 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | LESS | 0.5 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | MRTT | 7 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | NB | 12530 |
| Partying | DX | 2020 | REAL | OPEN | 0.03 |

I do not know if this the most efficient way of doing the thing, particularly about speed, memory consumption and conciseness, but it works and it is readable for me.